# Why do I always get the same result when using a ThreadLocalRandom class member?

Tags: java, spring

In my Spring app, if I have a `ThreadLocalRandom` class member that is set during construction:

```
public class RNG {
  private ThreadLocalRandom rng;
  
  public RNG() {
    rng = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
  }
  
  public int getInt() {
    return rng.nextInt(1000, 10000);
  }
}

// some other class
RNG a = new RNG();
a.getInt();
```

The first int that's returned is always the same, even across restarts of the app. If I instead modify the `getInt()` method:

```
public int getInt() {
  return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000, 10000);
}
```

I'll get psuedo-random values every time, even across restarts of the app (which is what I expect). This seems to only happen in Spring; I've tried the same in `jshell` and [Replit](https://replit.com/languages/java10) and don't see this behavior. For context, the Spring bean that generates the random number is autowired.

To be completely honest, I've removed random number generation from that part of the code altogether, and use an injected dependency instead, so I can unit test it.

This question is for me to get a better understanding of what is happening. As far as I'm aware, setting the class member during construction should provide a different value across restarts of the app.

Comment: Better to simply use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` when you want a `Random` instance, than to store the result (as it would allow other threads to then call the result). That aside, I'm surprised if the above code had the effect you describe, as `Random`'s default constructor takes into account `System.currentTimeMillis()`. In running your code myself, I get new results each time. Did you modify something else that would change the construction of the random values?

Comment: This might be a "you don't know what you don't know" situation; I'm not sure if Spring applies some of it's own "magic" that would affect the seed value, because I only see this weird behavior in Spring and nowhere else.

Comment: Because you are always instantiating this object in the same thread? There is no reason to have this as an instance member at all. Just remove it and use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` when you need it.

Comment: Storing `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` in the constructor in an instance variable is basically defeating the whole purpose of `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` in the first place (as it will actually leak 1 `ThreadLocalRandom` across threads with this, instead of having a fresh one per thread). I doubt it is only in Spring but if you write a program with multiple threads in which thread 1 initializes the stuff and others try create random values you will get the same result. The documentation of said class even mentions that you should use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the result of `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` in the constructor in an instance variable of a class is a bad idea. In fact beats the purpose of `ThreadLocalRandom` completely and you are then better of with an regular `Random` or `SecureRandom`.

That being said. This has nothing to do with Spring but the fact that you are storing the `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` result in an instance variable. The following program will yield the same result and it doesn't use Spring.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    System.out.println("Starting with RND " + rnd.getClass().getName() + " - " + rnd.hashCode());

    var executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        executor.submit(() -> System.out.println("Value: " + rnd.nextInt(1000, 10000)));
    }

    System.out.println("Waiting to finish!");

    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.awaitTermination(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {

    }
}
```

What happens is that the `Random` is initialized on the `main` thread and the seed etc. used by the random is stored in-memory for the `main` thread. Now you launch a new thread, it tries to find the seed for that thread and there is none, so it will seed always with 0, because no seed bound to that thread.

This is all due to storing the `ThreadLocalRandom` from main in a instance variable. The `ThreadLocalRandom` (as the name implies) uses thread bound seeds etc. to generate a random number. Which is why you should always use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` and not store the result of that in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so succinctly!